# PHP: Unable to call a public function

Tags: php, function, class, singleton

I have a page dashboard.php, which creates a merchant dashboard that shows deals submitted by the merchant. I'm simply trying to separate types of deals by checking to see if a deal is a suggested deal:

```
...
while ($deals->have_posts()) : $deals->the_post();
    $suggested_deal = SA_Post_Type::get_instance( $post->ID );
    $boolsuggesteddeal = $suggested_deal->is_suggested_deal();
    ...
```

However, the is_suggested_deal() line is causing the page to not display anything past that line.

The SA_POST_TYPE class is outlined below:

```
class SA_Post_Type extends Group_Buying_Deal {

...

public static function get_instance( $id = 0 ) {
    if ( !$id ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if ( !isset( self::$instances[$id] ) || !self::$instances[$id] instanceof self ) {
        self::$instances[$id] = new self( $id );
    }
    if ( self::$instances[$id]->post->post_type != parent::POST_TYPE ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return self::$instances[$id];
}

...

public function is_suggested_deal() {
    $term = array_pop( wp_get_object_terms( $this->get_id(), self::TAX ) );
    return $term->slug == self::TERM_SLUG;
}

...
```

Since the class and function are both public, why am I unable to call the function? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I can't figure out how to get error reporting on without showing all site users the errors, I'm on a live site. I tried creating an instance of SA_Post_Type(), but that alone cause the page to fail to load anything after that line.

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump` of `self::$instances`?

Comment: First, do you have error reporting on? Secondly, can you confirm that the `$suggested_deal` is actually an instance and not null?

Comment: This line is definitely working:
$suggested_deal = SA_Post_Type::get_instance( $post->ID );

Answer (score 0):

You have not created an instance of the class, do so like this...

```
$SA_Post_Type = new SA_Post_Type();
```

Then you are able to access the function...

```
$boolsuggesteddeal = $SA_Post_Type->is_suggested_deal();
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to have worked. I'm not sure why, but the constructor alone seems to stop the page from displaying anything after that line.

Answer (score 0):

Since is_suggested_deal is not a static function, you have to create a new instance of the SA_Post_Type class firstly.

```
$sa_post_type = new SA_Post_Type();
$boolsuggesteddeal = $sa_post_type->is_suggested_deal();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to have worked. I'm not sure why, but the constructor alone seems to stop the page from displaying anything after that line.